# How to set global providers in Angular2 2.0.0 RC.5?

Tags: angular

How do I set up global providers when using new feature that is NgModule? In the past I could do this:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
   GlobalServiceAAA,
   GLOBAL_PROVIDERS_BBB
]);
```

Using NgModule we bootstrap the app int his way:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

where in this case I place my global services and providers (assuming I do not want to provide them in every component)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

**NOTE : Shared feature module may contain your common services.**

**1. without [shared feature module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module)**

```
@NgModule({
  (...)
  providers: [ // <-------
    GlobalServiceAAA, GLOBAL_PROVIDERS_BBB
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**2. with [shared feature module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module)**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';      //<-------- Important

...
...


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,
                  SharedModule.forRoot(),                 //<----------Important
                  HomeModule,
                  routing
                ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }        from '@angular/common';

import { GlobalServiceAAA} from './path'                   //<-------- important
import { GLOBAL_PROVIDERS_BBB}   from './path';            //<-------- important
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [],
  exports:      [ CommonModule ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ GlobalServiceAAA,GLOBAL_PROVIDERS_BBB]   //<------important
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify them within the `providers` attribute of your NgModule.

```
@NgModule({
  (...)
  providers: [ // <-------
    GlobalServiceAAA, GLOBAL_PROVIDERS_BBB
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```