# Angular 2 RC.5 singleton global shared service

Tags: angular

I am trying to create **global singleton available services**. I have read this solution - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module, but it doesn't work for me.

I created **shared module** (this is my shorter example):

```
NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [ ShopCartComponent ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ShopCartComponent,
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot() : ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [
                ProductsService,
                ProductsActions
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

And in my **root** application module:

```
NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        SharedModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [
        provideStore({
           ... some stores ...
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But when I am trying to inject ProductsService | ProductsActions into **children** module, angular shows following error message:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for ProductsService!

It is my children module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: '', component: ProductsComponent }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [ ProductsComponent ]
})
export default class ProductsModule { }
```

I already imported SharedModule. Shoud I do something more?

**---------------- UPDATE -------------------**

I already solved my problem. I had to add ProductsModule into imports of root module. Like this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ProductsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        SharedModule.forRoot()
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The reason (I think) is that I wanted to load another module immediately in root route table, like this:

```
{ path: '', loadChildren: 'app/components/products/products.module' },
```

**Thanks guys for all help!**

Comment: If you want to share same instance, you should not declare providers array in root component. better to keep it in shared module.

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913976/how-to-set-global-providers-in-angular2-2-0-0-rc-5

Comment: It is not duplicate. Look at the code, I used solution from this url but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I would set your services into the `providers` attribute of your shared module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ ShopCartComponent ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ShopCartComponent,
  ],
  providers: [ // <-----
    ProductsService,
    ProductsActions
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  (...)
}
```

Comment: But it won't create few instances of every service? I added console.log into constructor and it looks like every module created his own service istance. The result is that my component from AppModule and component from ProductModule uses different objects.

Comment: This is actually a bad advice because https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#q-why-it-is-bad

Comment: Updated link for @ToanNguyen's comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-why-bad